# C++ и дополнительные библиотеки

Tags: windows, dll, qt, c++, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток.
Нужен совет сообщества касательно дополнительных библиотек в VS2010 EE и Qt Creator.
Постараюсь пояснить суть вопроса как можно проще:
Мне необходимо, чтобы моя программка (не содержащая ничего особенного, кроме функционала) могла запускаться на любом ПК с ОС Windows XP - 7. 
Идеальным был бы вариант создания приложения в вышеуказанных IDE без дополнительных библиотек.
Следующим по "хорошести" является вариант с включением библиотек в установочник, в данном случае нужны подсказки по реализации.
Ну и самым нежелательным советом с Вашей стороны был бы "Использовать IDE N".
Спасибо за время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересный выбор)
Для начала Qt Creator - использовать только если нужна Qt.
VS - построение виндового GUI и решение виндовых задач.

Я в своё время выбрал Qt и ни разу не пожалел.

Для того чтобы запускалось на любом компе достаточно либо настроить автоматическую сборку зависимостей, либо использовать статичесткую линковку, либо руками скидать в папку с программой нужные файлы из Qt.

Подробнее:

1. Сборка зависимостей - я сам точно не
      знаю, но есть утилиты автоматически
      их собирающие.
2. Статическая линковка - делает  боооольшой .exe`шник в котором
      всё что нужно уже есть. Правда
      придётся потратить ночь на
      перекомпиляцию Qt(у меня собиралась
      около 8 часов).
3. Скидать в папку с программой .dll`ки - самый простой путь. Нужен чистый комп и немного терпения. Компилим - копируем на чистый комп - запускаем - смотрим чего не хватает(ругаться будет - библиотека XXX не найдена, или что то вроде), копируем недостающий компонент из папки Qt - повторяем.

У вижуалки с этим проще(ибо не используются сторонние либы), но нет таких обширных возможностей как у Qt, так что выбор за тобой.

Answer (score 0):

Пиши в студии, все необходимые библиотеки уже есть в системе, скомпилированный exe-шник будет запускаться везде.